# Why was the only thread with the Reversal badge deleted?

Tags: discussion, badges, deleted-questions

I notice that the `Reversal` badge has been [awarded just a single time](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal), to @Macallan in 2015. I was rather sad to see that for something this rare - an answer apparently that good to a question apparently  that terrible - that the question was subsequently deleted.

But [this question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2903/121522) from @Glen_b says "It looks like OPs can only delete a question with an answer if there's only one answer and the answer isn't upvoted".

Does this mean that the question was deleted by mods? Is it okay to ask what happened there? And what pearls of wisdom I missed out on because that answer of >+20 was deleted?

Comment: I wrote about this topic once in Main Meta Stack Exchange with some suggestions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88709/the-lost-worlds-of-the-reversal-badge/197616#197616. The “update” part in the question body it was also me; in that time I came to the conclusion that most (or at least many) of “reversal” posts get deleted with time.

Comment: The question was a rant (likely to be deleted), but for the purpose of keeping as much content as possible alive ( in order to keep the back-end of the website, which new visitors can't see, as open as possible), it would be nice if the *links* to deleted content would still be available and the censorship only removes the content of the posts or whatever else is considered to be deleted.

Comment: @AndreSilva thanks for that read, and I like your suggestions.

Comment: mkt -- keep in mind the possibility that my comment that you quote may not be quite correct either. I do make mistakes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question you mention is [How to deal with a fake scientist?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55822/how-to-deal-with-a-fake-scientist/55824#55824), it got the -30 score and was deleted by the community, as voted by amoeba, kjetil b halvorsen, Xi'an on Nov 4 '17 at 13:25, neither of whom is or was a mod at that time. You gain the more [privileges](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) on the site with reputation, so at some point users are able to cast delete votes.

Please notice that the number of upvotes does not need to be a good measure of the quality of a question, or an answer. In this case, the answer is just a quote and a reference. I guess that it got so many upvotes because people upvoted it to say "I agree that the question is wrong", rather then to reward it for an exceptional quality.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the explanation and the clarification.

Comment: To satisfy the morbid curiosity of any who don't have the rep required to view deleted questions, [an archive is available](https://web.archive.org/web/20150912142518/https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55822/how-to-deal-with-a-fake-scientist/55824). It's only missing a few un-expanded comments and some votes versus the version at deletion (when the question was at -30 and the answer at +36).

Answer (score 8):

The question was deleted because enough votes were cast to delete it (none by a diamond moderator, as it happens). It was a rant, written in response to a frustrating experience on our site, not a real question; & perhaps by now rather embarrassing to the user that posted it—who will be, after all, four years older.

The answer took the question at face value: though it received many up-votes, it consisted of just a reference with a brief quotation.

Davidian, M. and Louis, T. A. (2012), [Why Statistics?](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/336/6077/12.summary) *Science*, vol. 336, no. 6077, p. 12.

Comment: Thanks! Nice to have that cleared up. And I appreciate the citation.

Comment: I upvoted the answer, and elected not to delete that thread, because it was a remarkably gentle and effective response to a question that (probably unintentionally) was little more than a trolling expedition.